# Encoding H264 with windows ffmpeg results in first few seconds being "blocky"

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, video-encoding

I am using the following code to transcode a 10mbps high quality 1280x720 H264 mp4 into a lower quality H264 mp4 with our logo watermarked on the video.

> ffmpeg.exe -i test.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex
>   overlay="(main_w)-(overlay_w):(main_h)-(overlay_h)" -c:v libx264
>   -profile:v main -preset slow -b:v 400k -r 30 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k -s 1280x720 -movflags faststart -f mp4 "test-done.mp4"

These settings work **wonderful** and after lots of tweaking to get this code, it produces  crisp, clear video for high action, stills, many different colors, etc.

**The problem** is that in the first few seconds of the video, the stream is very blocky. Then, after about 3-5 seconds, the stream "corrects" itself and the video is crisp and clear. Slowing down the rendering time by changing the preset to "veryslow" only marginally improves the first few seconds, but it increases render time dramatically.

How can I tell ffmpeg to pay more attention to the beginning of the video? Do I have to resort to 2-pass encoding? I don't want to nearly double the render time because only the first few seconds of the video have this problem. Could anyone modify my code to provide better encoding at the beginning of the file?

For reference, the original 10mbps mp4s are encoded by Premiere 5.0 and do not have blockiness at the beginning. This is something I have only witnessed with ffmpeg after transcoding.

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output that results form your command. Also, do you get the blockiness if you replace `-b:v 400k` with `-crf 18`?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard You're the ffmpeg-man, man! I always stumble upon your awesome answers on SO from searching google. Indeed `crf` instead of `b:v` fixed the problem. A crf of `18` resulted in ~4MB/s bitrate. After some testing, `-crf 26` results in approximately the bitrate I was shooting for (~400kbps) but the encoding blockiness in the beginning of the file is now gone. Cheers to you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. What is the use case for your output? What is the significance of 400k? I recommend removing `-s` and appending scale to your filtergraph so the behavior is more predictable: `"overlay=W-w:H-h,scale=1280:-2"`. Since you mentioned Premiere you might like [How to encode with `ffmpeg` from Adobe Premiere Pro](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/PremierePro).

Comment: We have a low bandwidth target audience. I never knew about the native `UT Video` encoder for ffmpeg, and the `frameserver` ability. These are both new to me. I'll also try out the scaling tweak. Thanks again :)

Comment: It's not a problem **FFmpeg** but rather of the x264 encoder you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @LordNeckbeard for the solution. It seems ffmpeg encodes x264 way better using `-crf` instead of `-v:b`.

So `-crf 26` worked perfectly to eliminate the blockiness at the beginning of the video encoding process.

My final code is now:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i test.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 26 -c:a libvo_aacenc -movflags faststart -f mp4 "test-done.mp4"
```

Comment: Not working for me. webm -> mp4. Mp4 file 1h duration still has delay.

Comment: @AlexSham my post was from 2014, ffmpeg has changed a lot in 7 years. I suggest googling for articles on ffmpeg encoding that were written in 2020/2021.

Comment: I'm not downvoting, just leaving comment here for others, who may face same problem, that they are not alone.

Comment: I don't know how many days I would have spent trying to solve the similar problem had it not been for this answer. Thank you!